# SQL Subquery more than 1 value

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-server-2016

I'm having a problem with a subquery which hopefully someone can help me with.

If I run the following:

```
select t4.code from OITM T0
 INNER JOIN DLN1 T1 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
 INNER JOIN ODLN T2 ON T2.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
 INNER JOIN ITM10 T3 ON T3.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
 LEFT JOIN ODCI T4 ON T4.[AbsEntry] = T3.[ISCommCode]
 WHERE T2.DocEntry = '7060'
```

The result is:
[image]

Although in some cases there may be multiple rows where the value matches those desired and others that don't at the same time.

I have written a query which has a subquery to check against these results and display a message if the [code] column in any row does not contain something specific:

```
IF(
(SELECT
    T4.Code
FROM OITM T0
 INNER JOIN DLN1 T1 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
 INNER JOIN ODLN T2 ON T2.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
 INNER JOIN ITM10 T3 ON T3.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
 LEFT JOIN ODCI T4 ON T4.[AbsEntry] = T3.[ISCommCode]
 WHERE T2.DocEntry = '7060') NOT IN ('22030010','22030001','22030009')
)
BEGIN
SELECT 'MESSAGE'
END
```

Obviously this won't compile if it has to return more than 1 row:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

HAVING and COUNT don't work as they compile without displaying the message which is obviously wrong.

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Many thanks.

Comment: How about just adding a `where` clause to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking if there are such lines, you can use `EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ...)
```

In your case I would make the select `distinct` to return a specific value only once:

```
select DISTINCT t4.code from OITM T0 ...
```

**UPDATE**

As [@gordon-linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) pointed out, you could filter out the unwanted values like this:

```
select distinct t4.code from OITM T0
...
where T2.DocEntry = '7060' and t4.code not in ('22030010','22030001','22030009')
-- using AND instead of ):  ^^^
-- so one ( will be enough between EXISTS and SELECT
```

Putting it together:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ....  where T2.DocEntry = '7060' and t4.code not in ('22030010','22030001','22030009'))
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Could you help me with the syntax following the EXISTS please? It gives a syntax error for the NOT IN when I use IF EXISTS(...)

Comment: Aw, maybe this is what @gordon-linoff meant. This is how to make the subquery run properly: `SELECT T4.Code ...  WHERE T2.DocEntry = '7060' AND T4.code NOT IN ('22030010','22030001','22030009')`. Adding an update to the post.

Comment: I don't think this works. It compiles but does not display the message.

Comment: @JohnCobby can you run the subquery first? Just to make sure the message appears on the right case.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. The message should display on this case, as the two [code] results are not one of the three desired values.

Comment: So, I don't understand :) You want to display 'Message', when any of the selected codes are not in the desired set, `('22030010','22030001','22030009')` ?

Comment: I've figured it out! You were on the right track and I wouldn't have gotten it without your or Gordon's suggestions so thanks. I took out the NOT IN and had it only check against NULL ( WHERE T2.DocEntry = 7189 AND T4.Code IS NULL) which seems to work. Thanks again.